# jquery function not working using Updatepanel in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I am using the textbox to search a record from gridview, without update panel, the search works fine, but when i use update panel it does not.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtSearchbox').keyup(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var searchKey = $('#txtSearchbox').val();
        $("#GridView1 tr td:nth-child(3)").each(function () {
            var cellText = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            if (cellText.indexOf(searchKey) >= 0) {
                $(this).parent().show();
            }
            else {
                $(this).parent().hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Grid

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <input type="text" id="txtSearchbox"/>
        <input type="button" id="btnsearch" value="Search"/>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" ScrollBars="Vertical" Height="500px" runat="server">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                          Width="100%"
                          BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4"
                          Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical"
                          OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnDataBound="OnDataBound"
                          CssClass="table table-responsive table-striped table-hover" EmptyDataText="No Record Found..."
                          RowStyle-Height="7px">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle"
                                       HeaderStyle-Width="40px">
                        <asp:boundfield datafield="OrderID" headertext="OrderID"/>
                        <%--
                        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                        --%>
                </Columns>
                <EmptyDataRowStyle Width="1195px" HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#C2D69B"/>
                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE"/>
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"/>
                <HeaderStyle Height="10px" VerticalAlign="Middle" BackColor="#6B696B" CssClass="tb_font"
                             ForeColor="White"/>
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White"/>
            </asp:GridView>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **keydown** instead of **keyup**.

```
$(function () {
  $("[id*=txtspegqty]").keydown(function () {
    //calculate total for current row
    var val7 = $(this).val() == "" ? 0 : $(this).val();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can fix this issue using any of the following two options:

**Option 1**

Set `ClientIDMode="static"` on `asp:GridView` element

**Option 2**

Update the jquery selector code like this:

```
$("#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> tr td:nth-child(3)")
```